# Getting Custom Error Message Array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just trying to find out the best way to get my custom error message working. Isset does not seem to work in codeigniter.

And for some reason my inputs are displaying the number `'1'`

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Step_3 extends MX_Controller { 

private $error = array();

public function index() {
  if(($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
    $data['db_hostname']    = $this->input->post('db_hostname');
  }

  if ($this->error['db_hostname']) {
    $data['error_db_hostname'] = $this->error['db_hostname'];
  } else {
    $data['error_db_hostname'] = '';
  }

  if ($this->input->post('db_hostname')) {
    $data['db_hostname'] = $this->input->post('db_hostname');
  } else {
    $data['db_hostname'] = 'localhost';
  }
}

private function validate() {
  if (!$this->input->post('db_hostname')) {
    $this->error['db_hostname'] = 'Hostname required!';
  }
}

} // End Of
```

**On View File Sample**

```
<input type="text" name="db_hostname" value="<?php echo $db_hostname; ?>" id="input-db-hostname" class="form-control" size="50"/>
<?php if ($error_db_hostname) { ?>
<div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_db_hostname; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "validate" function doesn't return anything, so your first if statement will never be true.
Also at the moment the input will automatically have a value of 'localhost'. It may be better to test for an empty string and strip spaces just in case like this:

```
if ("" == trim($this->input->post('db_hostname')))
```

Comment: What about this area $this->error['db_hostname'] can not put isset

Comment: What happens if you explicitly give a value to error['db_hostname'] and then use `(isset($this->error['db_hostname']))` does it evaluate correctly then?

Comment: no keeps saying can not use isset I tried null ! ==

Comment: Message now showing but I have tried it again but now saying  Undefined index: db_localhost bug is here $this->error['db_hostname']

Comment: Try using array_key_exists instead http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Also, I noticed that my original answer is not entirely true, your original !$this->input->post('db_hostname') should really evaluate as false if it is an empty string, so i'm going to amend my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55950/discussion-between-acoderslife-and-f3cp).

Comment: When add the "" == trim it removes the input value is there away to use that but keep the input value